# Javascript Wordpress Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Can anyone quickly look at this and see why jquery doesn't seem to be working? It was working earlier today, and I'm not sure what I could have touched that would cause it to stop.

I have a jsfiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nqdb3/
But if that's not good for troubleshooting this I can provide the actual site.

Comment: I set it up for staging at www.delsilencio.net/staging/wordpress login and pass is both temporarily "silencio"

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't log in, But I can tell you that many times I have encountered jQuery problems in wordpress both in admin and front end.

These usual suspects are plugins but it happened to me in the past without even touching the site.

1) start **disabling** all plugins one by one - this will eliminate the possibility of different scripts that cause it. If you were lucky, you will discover the culprit.
2) upload the js folder from the same wordpress installation. 
  -- download the same version you already have
  -- upload the js directory under **wp-includes** - all of it. and replace your current directory .

For me it worked many (many) times.